# Naming conventions for DTOs if C# and JavaScript Apps are talking to each other

Tags: c#, typescript, naming-conventions

The naming conventions for a TypeScript class entity say that I should use camelCase for my attribute names in TypeScript.

So like:

```
export class Bird {
   type: string;
   nameOfBird: string;
}
```

But the naming conventions in C# say that I should prefix class attributes with an _:

```
public class Bird {
   public string _type {get; set;}
   public string _nameOfBird {get; set;}
}
```

But when sending those as JSON between my apps, I get a conflict, because I do not know whether I should use the camelCase or _case in my JSON object. And it also seems to make the marshalling harder.

How do you handle this? Just ignore one of the guidelines or do the marshalling between both?

Comment: "naming conventions in C# say, that I should prefix class attributes with an _" There is no such rule in C#. Maybe there´s one within your company?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve both - by just using serialization-attributes:

```
public class Bird {
    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string _type {get; set;}
    [JsonProperty("nameOfBird")]
    public string _nameOfBird {get; set;}
}
```

or even

```
[JsonProperty("type")]
public string AnyCompletelyDifferentName { get; set; }
```

Apart from this there´s no convention in C# for prefixes on public members. Maybe there exists one within your company, however.

Comment: I guess the _-convention was maybe for private members... but typescript has for sure the convention to make public members camelCase, right? Or how do I understand this link: https://makecode.com/extensions/naming-conventions

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the _ prefix for attributes is a C# naming convention, but, assuming that you are right, at least for your company, there is a very nice way to solve the paradox you've just presented. Create:

```
private string _nameOfBird;
public string nameOfBird {
    get {
        return _nameOfBird;
    }
    set {
        _nameOfBird = value;
    }
}
```

and this way you respect both conventions.